# Insert / Update records in SQL Server from Dataframe using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I get the data in a CSV file from client. I would like to clean the data i.e. drop invalid rows and then push the data to SQL server table using python.

For data insertion, I am using below code and it works fine but I am not able to figure it out fastest way to update the existing record. Meaning, If some record (key MDMID) already exists, do not insert it rather update the existing record.

```
 list_of_tuples = df_total.values.tolist()
 sql_statement="insert into Table1(MDMID,IdentifierTypeID,IdentifierCountry,IdentifierValue) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
 cursor = con.cursor()
 cursor.fast_executemany = True
 cursor.executemany(sql_statement, list_of_tuples)
 con.commit()
```